# why libcore.io.ErrnoException: kill failed: ESRCH (No such process) in android?

Tags: android

### Here the below code i am using

```
try {
Runtime rnTm=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process execLang = rnTm.exec(new String[]{"getprop", "persist.sys.language"});
mCurrLocale = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (execLang.getInputStream())).readLine();
execLang.destroy();
Process execCountry = rnTm.exec(new String[]{"getprop", "persist.sys.country"});
mCurrCountry = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader    (execCountry.getInputStream())).readLine();
execLang.destroy();
Log.e("", "Device locale: "+mCurrLocale+" Co:"+mCurrCountry);
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 return;
 }
catch (SecurityException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
return;
```

}

```
It's working fine some phones and tablet.
```

But some time it causes my app to freeze and give the following result in logcat.

```
I/System  ( 1511): Failed to destroy process 1547
I/System  ( 1511): libcore.io.ErrnoException: kill failed: ESRCH (No such process)
I/System  ( 1511):      at libcore.io.Posix.kill(Native Method)
I/System  ( 1511):      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.kill(ForwardingOs.java:77)
I/System  ( 1511):      at      java.lang.ProcessManager$ProcessImpl.destroy(ProcessManager.java:257)
```

### Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

if it works on some device and not on others that means that you have to catch it in your exception and keep the program silent.

i suggest to add a catch with generic exception below your code:

```
catch (Exception ge) {
 ge.printStackTrace();
 return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this workaround (i did not try it)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/VcjXWBosQ88

maybe it can help you

```
finally {
       destroyProcess(process);           
}


private static void destroyProcess(Process process) {
    try {
        if (process != null) {
            // use exitValue() to determine if process is still running. 
            process.exitValue();
        }
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
        // process is still running, kill it.
        process.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Process.exitValue():
"Returns the exit value of the native process represented by this object.  It is available only when the native process has terminated."

Doesn't look like it guarantees destroying the process.